# Send HTML email including CSS style sheet via PHP

Tags: php, html, css, email

I want to send a HTML page that contains CSS stylesheet to an email account. The problem is that the CSS style sheet is not visible at all. Do I have to inline every CSS styling? It seems to be highly inefficient method. Any others ideas ?

Below is the PHP code for sending the email :

```
<?php
$to = "myaccount@gmail.com";

// subject
$subject = "Test mail";

// message
$message = file_get_contents("index.html");

// from
$from = "myaccount@gmail.com";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= "From:" . $from;

// Mail it
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need to use inline CSS. Most email services such as Google (especially) will trash external CSS.

Comment: When writing HTML for Emails, think of the Internet in 1996.

Comment: I usually embed my styles in a sheet in the `<head>` for emails and then refer to the classes for element inline.

Comment: @MackieeE nested frames, tables, marquees, under construction gifs, blinking text?

Comment: You can technically re-render your email before sending. Just load grab the HTML doc, create <script></script> tags in there, and grab the contents of your CSS file and put it in between. This will give the same result, but should be a lot faster, easier and more generic than re-writing all your emails :S

Comment: you can mine encode attach a stylesheet into an email and link it in using the src [CID:128397469876234] style thingie (can't remember the correct term for it)

Comment: If you're using this for a newsletter or something similar, it's also good practice to include a link/text to the affect of `"Email not displaying properly?"` where you can setup a page with an external stylesheet, with no limitations.

Comment: @KennyThompson Well, some of that hehe ;)

Comment: Here are some [CSS inlining tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code/17882057#17882057) that can help relieve some of your pain.

Answer (score 3):

Google, Outlook, Yahoo all the major email service providers do not allow CSS external files. It may sound antiquated that they have opted for inline styles and tables to render a proper email message with any styling.

It may be tedious to code but companies like https://litmus.com/ and envato will help with some templates and formatting issues.

my 2¢'s: email providers can't trust all sources of information being sent and so this is a way of keeping the malicious code at bay.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to just put a `<style>` block with all the CSS inside it somewhere in the `index.html` body. Some email clients/portals cut all the CSS embedded in the header with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." >`. As a result not using inline CSS may cause your emails to appear 'broken' or simply look bad on accounts with `@gmail.com` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Within your index.html file, include a `<style>` tag as below.

```
<style>
.class{
style: attribute; 
}
</style>";
```

That should work, if not then I may recommend hosting your stylesheet on a website and including a `<link>` tag similar to the one below in the head of your index file

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.yourstylesheet.com'>";
```

Either of those methods should help with your problem.

Comment: will this work the same with a js code? (jQuery and a js library)

Answer (score 0):

Just embed the css-code into the `<head>` of that html-email.

Comment: Inline CSS is recommended, because not all mail clients support CSS in the `<head>`.

Comment: in case if i am use `bootstrap` means how can i add css? or if i add all the css in `inline format  ` ??

Comment: Yes, add it inline.