# How to email an HTML file with external css and js using Java Mail API?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, html-email

I have a static HTML page which gets generated after some operation. The HTML file contains iframe, external CSS, JS, XML, HTML files. How do I send the exact rendered HTML in the mail using Java mail API? I know I can type the HTML like

```
message.setContent("<html><body><h1>This is actual message</h1></body></html>","text/html" );
```

But I want to send an html page like

```
message.setContent("index.html","text/html" );
```

index.html contains external css, js, xml files.

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637548/send-html-email-including-css-style-sheet-via-php

Comment: Are there actual email clients that load external CSS, and even load and execute JS? To have good compatibility with Mail clients I think you'll have to inline CSS and not use JS at all in html emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the message content from a file like this:

```
message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
            new FileDataSource("index.html", "text/html")));
```

Note that many mail readers will not access the external css or images when displaying the message.

The JavaMail FAQ has several entries related to sending html messages, starting [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendhtml).  This [guide to css support in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) will also help.